# Instant weapon change

Tags: team-fortress-2

When I play Team Fortress 2 and want to switch weapons I have to select one using my the keyboard's number keys (1, 2, 3, ...) and press fire button on the mouse to switch to that weapon. Alternatively I can select a weapon using the mouse's scroll wheel and then pressing the fire button to switch. I find this very annoying since it takes too much time using this method. Is there a setting that makes the game switch weapons immediately when I press a number key or scroll?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Go to Options, open the Keyboard tab, click Advanced... and then tick the "Fast weapon switch" option. This'll make switching instant when you press a number key or scroll.

Comment: And don't forget that pressing Q switches to your last used weapon

Comment: At this point, I wonder why fast switch isn't the only type of switch, given that there are weapons out there which are *only beneficial because of quick switch time*.

Comment: @Zibbobz: Backwards compatibility.  The old GoldSrc engine (Half Life 1) didn't do fast switching, and some people got it [wired into their muscle memory](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/DamnYouMuscleMemory).

Answer (score 10):

In addition to the fast weapon switch previously mentioned, what I do is rebind:

Primary weapon to mousewheel-up

Pistol to mousewheel-down

Melee weapon to mousewheel-click

That way, I never scroll past a weapon I want.  All you have to do is flick the mousewheel.

Answer (score 4):

I have a [5 button mouse](http://www.logitech.com/en-us/428/359).  So I use bind my spare buttons directly to my primary and alternate weapons.  It doesn't work that great for spy/engineer, but for a medic where I am mostly using the Medigun/Syringe gun it is great.

I have updated my autoexec.cfg like so.

```
bind "MOUSE3" "slot3; +attack; wait 50; -attack"
bind "MOUSE4" "slot2; +attack; wait 50; -attack"
bind "MOUSE5" "slot1; +attack; wait 50; -attack"
```