# How to change a class' default weapon slot?

Tags: team-fortress-2

I want to change the default weapon slot for some classes. In particular Medic's offensive [primary weapon](https://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Medic#Primary) is an odd choice, practically in all instances I switch to the [secondary slot](https://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Medic#Secondary) (healing) after spawning.

Answer (score 1):

You can enable the option to remember your last used weapon.  As I recall, it's in the Advanced Options menu.

Still, the first time you spawn during a map, you'll have to manually switch.

On a side note, the default item is always your primary weapon.  That might confuse people who play Spy because it defaults to your knife... but if you've ever looked at the Spy's slots, his revolver is his *secondary* weapon.

Comment: "remember the active weapon between lives" isn't useful for all classes based on my experience, but could  be in Medic config,

Comment: As a long overdue side note, have you considered using the Crusader's Crossbow as the Medic's Primary weapon?  It's the only thing in the game that can heal from a distance.

Comment: A valid point, but can't solve the request.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, it's not possible to spawn with your secondary weapon already out. The second best thing I could think of is enabling [Quick Switch](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/4749/158613). If you have it enabled you can switch between your weapons by pressing 'Q' more easily.

Comment: I assumed that spawning isn't possible, but I've seen people discussing about scripting to switch the default weapon on spawn. "Fast weapon switch" and "last weapon used" (key bind) aren't the same!